# Created bootable drive using dd, now my 1tb hard drive has only 268mb

Tags: partition, dd, macos, storage, external-hdd

I'm using a 2020 Macbook Air (M1 version). I've been trying to work out how to install linux to use some programs I need for data analysis, and today tried to follow this guide: https://corellium.com/blog/linux-m1. It didn't work at all, I probably got something wrong, and now my external 1tb hard disk, which I copied a bootable linux image to using the dd command, is formatted weird so that it only allows me to write 268mb to it. I've tried erasing and reformatting using Disk Utility, but no luck. Any guesses?

Note: it was an empty drive, I didn't lose any files.

Comment: Did you use your drive as a flash drive, so this applies? Reset USB flash that was dd'd to make it usable again, reuse
https://askubuntu.com/questions/939230/formatting-a-usb-stick-unable-to-operate-usb/939266#939266 & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive & 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216152/usb-disk-read-only-cannot-format-turn-off-write-protection Looks very experimental to use Linux on M1.

Answer (score 1):

Re-create the partition table:

#### msdos

```
sudo parted /dev/sdX mklabel msdos
```

#### GPT

```
sudo parted /dev/sdX mklabel gpt
```

Add a formatted ext4 primary partition:

```
sudo parted -a none /dev/sdX  mkpart primary ext4 0 100%
```

Replace `sdX` with your device name.

Comment: Hi, I didn't follow this advice, I just erased the disk using diskutils. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @MichaelBeavitt Yes you can create a new partition table using  `fdisk`