# Unable to Format my HDD

Tags: linux, partition, hard-disk, manjaro, external-hdd

A Few Days Back i was using my PC it had a decent Startup Everything was Just Fine, But Suddenly Screen Glitched & all Sort of went downhill afterwards.

I, as i'm a normie when it comes to Understanding  of Computer I hope Someone can give me a decent answer to my problem i even tried tried `dd` command & it ended up giving an error that it can't do any further as there is no space left to do so.

*Just so You know i tried basically every Common Command & Software on Linux*

Quite similar to this,
`dd; error writing  '/dev/sdX': No space left on device`

I don't remember the exact error message for which i'm sorry,
Anyways then i gave **parted -l** a try it gave the Message:

`Error: /dev/sda: unrecognised disk label Model: ATA ST31000525SV (scsi)                                             Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B Partition Table: unknown Disk Flags:`

Just like *Pablo* did, for more Detail Check his Article; [Unable to format HDD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656408/unable-to-format-hdd)

However,my `dmesg` differed i.e, `[   33.034716] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 5 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0 [   33.034719] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read`

So, can anyone tell me what is wrong? & please keep it simple:)
oh my disk is a 1TB Seagate HD, Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

The commands you show are a bit questionable, but the error message is quite unambiguous:

There's something physically wrong with your hard drive. That's not a problem you can fix in software.

This aligns nicely with that disk model being introduced in 2009. It also has only 32 MB buffer – all in all, it's an old, and slow, hard drive that I'm not at all surprised has reached its end of life.

If making sure all SATA connections to your hard drive are properly plugged in didn't yield relief, then you'll need to buy a new hard drive (1TB entry level is ~30€) or SSD ([1TB entry level ~40€](https://www.heise.de/preisvergleich/?cat=hdssd&xf=252_960%7E4832_1%7E4836_2&sort=p&hloc=de&v=k&t=v)), where the latter is going to be significantly faster and the price difference might amortize within a year at current electricity prices.