# unable to partition usb device

Tags: linux, partition, usb

I'm running Debian/Bookworm. When I plug a USB stick in, I get the dmesg output below and the device also shows in lsblk as:

```
sdm           8:192  1     0B  0 disk
```

Here's the dmesg output:

```
root@transponder:~#dmesg
....
[96385.365179] usb 1-7.3: new high-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[96385.509006] usb 1-7.3: New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=5100, bcdDevice= 1.00
[96385.509015] usb 1-7.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[96385.509017] usb 1-7.3: Product: Patriot Memory
[96385.509019] usb 1-7.3: Manufacturer:         
[96385.509021] usb 1-7.3: SerialNumber: 070B2B5D08C16433
[96385.524931] usb-storage 1-7.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[96385.525303] scsi host8: usb-storage 1-7.3:1.0
[96386.740435] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access              Patriot Memory   PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[96386.740959] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg13 type 0
[96386.787994] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdm] Media removed, stopped polling
[96386.809960] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdm] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

When I try to partition it, here's what I get:

```
root@transponder:~# gdisk /dev/sdm
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Problem opening /dev/sdm for reading! Error is 123.
```

It also doesn't show up in gparted. Is the stick toast or can it be rehabilitated?

Comment: I have seen this before, if you did not have very sensitive information on this drive, do not waste your time. It's likely a brick.

Comment: Did you use flash drive as installer created by dd. That does not have partitions and then cannot be repartitioned as random data in partition table. Reset USB flash that was dd'd to make it usable again, reuse
https://askubuntu.com/questions/939230/formatting-a-usb-stick-unable-to-operate-usb/939266#939266 & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive & 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216152/usb-disk-read-only-cannot-format-turn-off-write-protection